# Handling unregistered Celery tasks during continuous deployment

Tags: python, celery

I have a setup of multiple Celery workers on different machines. The tasks can get added at any time with a continous deployment process. So, at any point different workers may have different sets of tasks, even though they are on the same task queue.

So, the following state is possible:

- tasks on machine A: `add`
- tasks on machine B: `add`, `subtract`

Now, I call task `subtract`, machine A picks it up (round robin), and throws a `celery.exceptions.NotRegistered` exception. The task fails and is never retried again.

Is there a clean pattern where machine A would simply ignore tasks that are not in its registry so other workers that do could pick them up? I cannot use queues, for example, because the tasks are on the same queue (just diverging due to deployment, for example).

Of course, I can detect the failure and retry on the client, but it seems like it should be a common enough pattern to have built-in support, but I just can't find anything about this.

I tried `task_acks_late` and `task_reject_on_worker_lost` configuration parameters but they didn't seem to be relevant.

Machine A:

```
app = Celery('worker', broker='pyamqp://guest@localhost//', backend='redis://localhost:6389/0')

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Machine B:

```
app = Celery('worker', broker='pyamqp://guest@localhost//', backend='redis://localhost:6389/0')

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

@app.task
def subtract(x, y):
    return x - y
```

Client:

```
>>> result = app.send_task('subtract', args=[3, 2])
>>> res.get()
>>> 1
>>> result = app.send_task('subtract', args=[3, 2])
>>> res.get()
...
celery.exceptions.NotRegistered: subtract
```